# form validation does not clear after function call

Tags: python, html, regex, flask, jinja2

I am working on a piece of code that checks for valid user credentials, as so in my app:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None

        if not username:
            error = 'Username is required'
        if validate_user(username) is False:
            error = 'Usernames must be 5 to 10 in length, not start with a number and use only lowercase.'
        elif not email:
            error = 'Email is required'
        elif not password:
            error = 'Password is required'
```

in the function for validation of the *user*, here is the code:

```
def validate_user(user):
    valid_user = re.compile(r'\D{1}[D\d]{4,9}')
    matched = valid_user.match(user)
    if matched:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

in my form using [jinja](/questions/tagged/jinja) i have the following code, specific to the *user* part:

```
{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="45"
           title="cannot start with a number, have a length of 5 to 10 non-special characters" required>
   </div>
```

As I am testing this function the page doesn't go past the registration even though everything seems in place. Really spinning my wheels on this, as it seems so trivial...

Comment: Not familiar with flask  or jinja but have a doubt about how you are rendering your template here  ?

Comment: The template is rendered by [tag:jinja], it takes a [tag:html] file and has certain markup to it. More info here https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/

Comment: Yea that i know but it was not there in the code , that's why i asked .

Comment: is this your complete register function? I would expect a return statement at the end. A redirect for example to the login form or something similar

Comment: @shiny - this is part of the complete code, yes it has a return at the end but it is omitted here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern `\D[D\d]{4,9}` matches any char except a digit, then 4-9 times either a `D` char or a digit. It is also unanchored without `$`, to the maximum length to have re.match return a match object is not 10

If you want for the username:

> Usernames must be 5 to 10 in length, not start with a number and use
> only lowercase.

```
\D[^A-Z]{4,9}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN3Pni/1)

Note that `\D` and `[^A-Z]` can also match spaces and newlines.

If those are not allowed, you can exclude `\s` from the range using a negated character class. As you are using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) in the code, you can omit the `^` anchor.

```
[^\s\d][^\sA-Z]{4,9}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9yOSD/1)

Comment: I did not know about the newline or spaces behavior. That's helpful. But for my the original regex I did notice the typo after this was posted for a bit. What is the reason for using the anchor, seems though as it works the same with and without for the original regex? For the test, tried 'user@12345' and 'user@1234' and both were valid.

Comment: @etch_45 Yes, user@12345 is valid but user@123456789 should not be valid. See https://regex101.com/r/rKP36C/1 If you omit the anchor, it will be valid. See https://regex101.com/r/QPJqdg/1

Comment: Alright, I see this now. Did a quick test before the comment.